# hibernate mapping with @Any and @JoinTable

Tags: java, hibernate

I have following tables in my database

```
IMAGE_TABLE {
   `ID`
   `NAME`
}

IMAGE_OBJECT {
   `IMAGE_ID`
   `OBJECT_ID`
   `OBJECT_TYPE`
}

CAR {
   `ID`
   `DESCRIPTION`
}

HOUSE {
   `ID`
   `DESCRIPTION`
}
```

IMAGE_OBJECT table links image to either car or house (depending on OBJECT_TYPE value).
In my ImageEntity I want to map field with single entity:

```
    @Any(
        metaColumn = @Column( table="IMAGE_OBJECT", name = "OBJECT_TYPE" ) )
    @AnyMetaDef(
        idType = "long",
        metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
            @MetaValue( value = "car", targetEntity = CarEntity.class ),
            @MetaValue( value = "house", targetEntity = HouseEntity.class )
        } 
    )
    @JoinTable(name = "IMAGE_OBJECT",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "IMAGE_ID", unique = true)           
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID")
        }     
    )
    private AbstractEntity object;
```

But this mapping leads to exception:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @Any requires an explicit @JoinColumn(s)
```

I've also tried mapping using `@ManyToAny` and then using setter and getter to store single element in collection:

```
    @ManyToAny(
        metaColumn = @Column( table="IMAGE_OBJECT", name = "OBJECT_TYPE" ) )
    @AnyMetaDef(
        idType = "long",
        metaType = "string",
        metaValues = {
            @MetaValue( value = "car", targetEntity = CarEntity.class ),
            @MetaValue( value = "house", targetEntity = HouseEntity.class )
        } 
    )
    @JoinTable(name = "IMAGE_OBJECT",
        joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "IMAGE_ID", unique = true)           
        },
        inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "OBJECT_ID")
        }     
    )
    private Set<AbstractEntity> objects;
```

This works unless I try to clear `objects` or remove an element from it:

```
objects.clear();
```

Giving me weird exception:

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [delete from IMAGE_OBJECT where IMAGE_ID=? and OBJECT_ID=?];
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (3 > number of parameters, which is 2).
```

This is possibly a [bug in Hibernate](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7397) , so I can't use this mapping as well.

Is there any way I can map Any-relation using @JoinTable ?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with the last mapping, and writing setter and getter in the following way:

```
...
private Set<AbstractEntity> objects = new HashSet<AbstractEntity>();

...

public AbstractEntity getObject() {
    return objects.isEmpty() ? null : objects.get(0);
}

public void setObject(AbstractEntity object) {
    // objects.clear() results in weird exception
    objects = new HashSet<AbstractEntity>();
    if (object != null) {
        objects.add(object);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's still a nasty hack. Wish someone could comment on this, currently having the same problem :/

Comment: Same here... =T